# SQL ORDER BY on Subset of Data in Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a table structure as below:

```
Table: Details
ID      |  ParentName       |  ChildName
1       |   ParentA         |  ChildA
2       |   ParentA         |  ChildC
3       |   ParentA         |  ChildB
4       |   ParentB         |  ChildL
5       |   ParentB         |  ChildS
6       |   ParentB         |  ChildT
7       |   ParentB         |  ChildM
8       |   ParentB         |  ChildP
9       |   ParentB         |  ChildR
10      |   ParentC         |  ChildZ
```

I need to sort the ChildName in ascending order only when the ParentName is ParentB, for other ParentName - sorting should not be applied
So basically I need to sort only the subset of data ie. when ParentName = ParentB, and other data should remain as it is.

I tried the below query, but it is sorting all records - but I need to sort only for ParentB

```
SELECT * FROM DETAILS WITH (NOLOCK) ORDER BY ParentName , ChildName
```

Expected result is: Sorting is done only for ParentName = ParentB, other data is same.

```
ID      |  ParentName       |  ChildName
1       |   ParentA         |  ChildA
2       |   ParentA         |  ChildC
3       |   ParentA         |  ChildB
4       |   ParentB         |  ChildL
7       |   ParentB         |  ChildM
8       |   ParentB         |  ChildP
9       |   ParentB         |  ChildR
5       |   ParentB         |  ChildS
6       |   ParentB         |  ChildT
10      |   ParentC         |  ChildZ
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How would the expected result looks like ?

Comment: [Bad habits: putting `nolock` everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY` clause

```
order by ParentName,
    case when ParentName = 'ParentB' then ChildName end,
    ID
```

Comment: This would sort by parentname first, this was unspecified, but since the questioner accepted, ...